# Solidity: Storing values in mapping causes high gas. Can I use bytes array?

Tags: solidity

I'm working with a contract which can pay revenues. This is how the main part of my code looks more or less:

```
for(uint i = 1; i <= newestId; i++)
{
    uint unitsAmount = user.units[i];
    if(unitsAmount == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    RevenueData storage r = RevenueData[i];
    revenue = revenue.add(r.revenueForUnit.mul(unitsAmount));
    uint j = i + 1;
    user.units[j] = user.units[j].add(unitsAmount);
    user.units[i] = 0;
}
```

If user takes revenue with id 6, but misses 7, and 8 is the newest, code will automatically give also revenue 7 to him.

This is working as expected, but the problem is it generates a lot of gas, on the ropsten with 1 gas price it takes 7 cents with newestId = 1, but ~28 cents when newestId is 7. On the main network it will be even 10 times more expensive because of gas price, so it makes the code impossible to withdraw any revenue.

I guess it's possible to make it somehow better. Can I replace mapping storage with bytes array and somehow pushing or pulling ints there?

I'm totally new with bitwise operations. The maximum amount of units is 200000000, so I guess if I can do it with bytes array it needs to work with uint24? And then save it in < 0, < 24, < 48? But these are only my suspections based on quick googling.

May I gently ask for any kind of tips or help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant understand what your code does, could you please explain what is your idea and what the variables are?. I am a bit puzzled by: `uint j = i + 1;
    user.units[j] = user.units[j].add(unitsAmount);` becaue you seem to read this result in the next iteration of the loop `uint unitsAmount = user.units[i];`, what are you trying to do in general?

Comment: Admin can make revenue anytime, every new payment it saves in mapping (key = ++payment index, value = RevenueData) how much wei is saved for this payment, how many tokens were during that payment and how much wei is for one unit. When user buys 100 tokens from admin, it saves in mapping (key = payment + 1, value += 100). User can take wei whenever he wants. It loops through payment 1 to newest and counts how much wei he can get. If user gets wei from old payment, it becomes still able for the newer. And it keeps until it's on the newest one. He will be able to get  wei only after new payment.